# Using Mockito verify a method was called with an argument containing a substring

Tags: java, unit-testing, mockito

When `logger.error` is called, there are many different things that can be passed as the 3rd argument.

How can I verify that `e` contains a specific substring?

This is my production code ..

```
public class MyClass {

    private ILogger logger = Slf4jLogbackLogger
            .generateLogger(MyClass.class.getClassLoader().getResource("log_messages.properties"));

    public void doSomething() {
        logger.info(Optional.empty(), "MyClass.doSomething");

        try {
            .. do things // throw new RuntimeException("something");

        } catch (Exception e) {
            logger.error(Optional.empty(), "HANDLE_EXCEPTION", e);
        }
    }
}
```

My test code ..

```
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
public class TestMyClass {

    @Mock
    private ILogger logger;

    @InjectMocks
    @Spy
    private MyClass myClass = new MyClass();

    @Before
    public void init() throws Exception {
        MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
    }

    @Test
    public void testMyClass() throws Exception {

        try {
            myClass.doSomething();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            fail("Should not have thrown any exceptions");
        }
        Mockito.verify(logger, Mockito.times(1)).error(Optional.empty(), "HANDLE_EXCEPTION", "Contains something specific");
    }
}
```

This is the error I'm recieving ..

```
org.mockito.exceptions.misusing.InvalidUseOfMatchersException: 
Invalid use of argument matchers!
3 matchers expected, 1 recorded:

This exception may occur if matchers are combined with raw values:
    //incorrect:
    someMethod(anyObject(), "raw String");
When using matchers, all arguments have to be provided by matchers.
For example:
    //correct:
    someMethod(anyObject(), eq("String by matcher"));
```

Have tried things like below, but same error:

```
ArgumentCaptor<String> argument = ArgumentCaptor.forClass(String.class);
Mockito.verify(logger, Mockito.times(1)).error(Optional.empty(), "HANDLE_EXCEPTION", argument.capture());
```

Comment: I don't see how this exception could be thrown by the code you posted, since it's not using any matcher.

Comment: added an attempt that I removed by mistake, using `ArgumentCaptor `

Comment: Have you read the error message? Because it explains what you need to do, quite clearly: **all** the arguments must be matchers. What don't you understand in the detailed error message?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

All arguments during veryfying that `error` method was called on `logger` need to be `matchers` in your case. Here is an example of using `matchers` and mocking some Service class :

```
@ExtendWith(MockitoExtension.class)
public class SomeTestClass {

    private static class MyService {
        public void error(Optional<String> op, String msg1, String msg2) {

        }
    }

    @Test
    void testMethod() {
        MyService myService = Mockito.mock(MyService.class);
        myService.error(Optional.empty(), "This is error", "Some error appeared");
        Mockito.verify(myService, Mockito.times(1)).error(Mockito.any(), Mockito.eq("This is error"), Mockito.contains("error"));
    }
}
```

Here `Mockito.any()`, `Mockito.eq()`, `Mockito.contains()` are methods that return matchers.

To assert that method was invoked with `String` containing given substring use `Mockito.contains()` matcher. Here you can find more information about using [Matchers](https://www.baeldung.com/mockito-argument-matchers).